# Como fazer esse tipo de notificação

Tags: android

Como posso fazer esse tipo de notificação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo quando clica em limpar ela não sai da barra de notificação, também tem 2 botoes ali.
Gostaria de fazer exatamente igual a essa, já procurei bastante e não acho em local nenhum.

Comment: Apesar de ser um pergunta sem muitos detalhes, talvez seja algo realmente complicado de saber por onde começar, ao meu ver a questão não deve ser fechada, apenas talvez um pouco melhorada.

Comment: O que eu preciso fazer é uma barra de notificação que quando eu clicar no botão voltar do aparelho a aplicação não fecha e aparece essa mesma notificação acima. Se você clicar em limpar notificações ele nunca limpa a minha notificação e meu app ainda está rodando. Ao acionar o botão On e OFF o app desliga a funcionalidade que estava exemplo a funcionalidade de vibrar. Também temos o botão fechar que é aquele X. É isso que eu preciso fazer.

Comment: Sim a pergunta está clara, a resposta do @claudsan deve ajudar. Não comentei pra você, o meu comentário anterior foi para que votou para fechar a questão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar seu próprio layout como exemplo abaixo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        style="Custom Notification Title" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        style="Custom Notification Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Na activity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
        notification.contentView = contentView;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Existe outras maneiras de fazer isso mas acredito que com o seu próprio layout fica mais facil.

Aqui também tem um [exemplo(english)](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-notifications-3-applying-big.html)  sem o uso do layout.

Post [original no SO (english)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout)

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: consegui fazer pelo exemplo que você me mandou. Veja aqui:
http://imgur.com/DY4AZUW
Agora preciso fazer a programação dos botões. Sabe como posso fazer? Por exemplo estou testando o vibra call do celular, gostaria que quando clicar no botão azul ele pare com essa funcionalidade. O botão fechar posso usar System.exit(0);

Comment: Vou ver se encontro aqui como fiz, eu usei um botão se não estou enganado acho que utiliza igual um botão qualquer. Vou ver se encontro aqui e posto aqui.